# VC++ Express 2010 errors out on the self-assignment test of overloaded assignment operator of templated class

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

i'm trying to override the assignment operator and perform a self-assignment test, but VC++ Express 2010 gives me the following error for my code as show below:

1>c:\users\fatak\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ray tracer\ray tracer\test.h(22): error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'const Test *' to 'Test *const '

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

template <class T = unsigned int> class Test
{
public:
Test() : dummy(0U) {};
template <class U> Test(U value) : dummy(T(value)) {};
~Test() {};

template <class U> Test<T> &operator=(const Test<U> &rhs);

T getValue(void) const {return dummy;};

template <class U> friend class Test;
private:
T dummy;
};

template <class T> template <class U> Test<T> &Test<T>::operator=(const Test<U> &rhs)
{
if(this == &rhs)
    return *this;

dummy = T(rhs.dummy);

return *this;
}

#endif //__TEST_H__
```

Even when I change the operand to the templated overriden assignment operator to:

```
template <class T> template <class U> Test<T> &Test<T>::operator=(Test<U> & const rhs)
```

I get the following error:

1>c:\users\fatak\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\ray tracer\ray tracer\test.h(22): error C2440: '==' : cannot convert from 'Test *' to 'Test *const '

any idea why? or how I can perform a successfull self-assignment test anyone?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The types `Test<T>` and `Test<U>` are totally different types (unless T is U).

You cannot compare pointers to unrelated types. And they can't be the same anyway, because unrelated types cannot exist at the same address!

---

You should probably have one non-template `operator=(const Test<T>&)`, which might test for self-assignment if needed, and one `operator=(const Test<U>&)` which doesn't need the test.